# Segmentation fault(core dumped) in recursively listing of directories and files in C, Linux

Tags: c, linux, terminal, segmentation-fault, coredump

so basically the issue appears when I try to run a function which **recursively prints the paths for files and directories**. The issue that I am getting in terminal when I run the program is "**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**".

Any suggestions how I can solve this?

EDIT: MAX_LEN defined as 2048.

This is the code:

```
void list_recursive(char* path){
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent *dirent;
    char * name = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LEN);

    dir = opendir(path);    
    if(dir != NULL){
        printf("SUCCESS\n");
        while((dirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
            if(strcmp(dirent->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dirent->d_name, "..") != 0){
                sprintf(name, "%s/%s", path, dirent->d_name);
                printf("%s\n", name);
            }
        }
        free(name);
        if(dirent->d_type == DT_DIR){
            list_recursive(dirent->d_name);
        }   
        closedir(dir);  
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        printf("invalid directory path\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is anything printed before the fault?

Comment: Yes, it prints everything that needs to be printed, and then I get Segmentation fault.

Comment: regarding: `char * name = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LEN);`  1)  the expression: `sizeof(char)`  is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 as no effect. Including that expression just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.  2) when calling any of the heap allocation function: (`malloc` `calloc` `realloc`) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe when you exit the while:

```
dirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL
```

so, `dirent == NULL`. But then you have:

```
if(dirent->d_type == DT_DIR)
```

which is, dereferencing a NULL pointer - seg-faulty as they come. Perhaps you wanted this if **inside** the while?

As an aside, to debug this I just stuck a bunch of `printfs` in your code to pin-point the exact line of segmentation - that's good practice for small programs and a quick fix.

This works for me (fixing the recursion argument as well):

```
while((dirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
    if(strcmp(dirent->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dirent->d_name, "..") != 0){
        sprintf(name, "%s/%s", path, dirent->d_name);
        printf("%s\n", name);
        if(dirent->d_type == DT_DIR){
            list_recursive(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I put it inside the loop I get infinite loop, and if I am conditioning the if like this:` if(dirent->d_type == DT_DIR && dirent != NULL)`, I still get the same issue.

Comment: @ISimion the second part is because your if evaluates both expressions (actually just the first in this case, then crashes - you need to read up on this, C if evaluation). Regarding the infinite nature of the recursion, that's a structure problem with your code. Consider using the `return` value of the function instead of `void`, to end the recursion. If that's unclear, you can post it on another question. In any case your problem is exactly what I pointed out. You can comment it out to check (or first check the NULL, which is always true in your code...).

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, not infinite recursion - you want the recursion `if` inside the `if` inside the `while`, that should almost work (you need to pass on the full new path to the recursion).